# I want to create map that display USA state, when user click on state it will show that's state's cities. I'm using highchart

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highchart map, that displays the USA state and its counties, but I want to show all cities of the selected state and when someone clicks on the city map it will display pop up model

I want to display all cities of the selected state and when someone clicks on the city map it will display a pop-up model.
The code I'm using right now

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
const drilldown = async function (e) {
    // console.log('hover key', e.point.drilldown)
        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
            const chart = this,
                mapKey = `countries/us/${e.point.drilldown}-all`;

            // Handle error, the timeout is cleared on success
            let fail = setTimeout(() => {
                if (!Highcharts.maps[mapKey]) {
                    chart.showLoading(`<i class="icon-frown"></i> Failed loading ${e.point.name}`);
                    fail = setTimeout(() => {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }, 3000);

            // Show the Font Awesome spinner
            chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-3x"></i>');

           
                 var topology = await
```

fetch(`https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/${mapKey}.topo.json`)
.then(response => response.json());

```
            // Load the drilldown map
            // const topology = await fetch(`https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/${mapKey}.topo.json`)
            // .then(response => response.json());
            
            const data = Highcharts.geojson(topology);
            
            // Set a non-random bogus value
            data.forEach((d, i) => {
                d.value = i;
                console.log('data',d)
            });

            // Apply the recommended map view if any
            chart.mapView.update(
                Highcharts.merge(
                    { insets: undefined },
                    topology.objects.default['hc-recommended-mapview']
                ),
                false
            );

            // Hide loading and add series
            chart.hideLoading();
            clearTimeout(fail);
            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
                name: e.point.name,
                data,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            });
        }
      
    };

    // On drill up, reset to the top-level map view
    const drillup = function (e) {
        if (e.seriesOptions.custom && e.seriesOptions.custom.mapView) {
            e.target.mapView.update(
                Highcharts.merge(
                    { insets: undefined },
                    e.seriesOptions.custom.mapView
                ),
                false
            );
        }
    };


    (async () => {

        const topology = await fetch(
            'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.topo.json'
        ).then(response => response.json());

        const data = Highcharts.geojson(topology);

        const mapView = topology.objects.default['hc-recommended-mapview'];

        // Set drilldown pointers
        data.forEach((d, i) => {
            d.drilldown = d.properties['hc-key'];
            d.value = i; // Non-random bogus data
        });
       
        // Instantiate the map
        Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
            chart: {
                events: {
                    drilldown,
                    drillup,
                    thrilup
                }
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Highcharts Map Drilldown'
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 0,
                minColor: '#E6E7E8',
                maxColor: '#005645'
            },

            mapView,

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                map: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#EEDD66'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                data,
                name: 'USA',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.properties.postal-code}'
                },
                custom: {
                    mapView
                }
            }],

            drilldown: {
                activeDataLabelStyle: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    textDecoration: 'none',
                    textOutline: '1px #000000'
                },
                drillUpButton: {
                    relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
                    position: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 60
                    }
                }
            },

            thrilup: {
                activeDataLabelStyle: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    textDecoration: 'none',
                    textOutline: '1px #000000'
                },
                drillUpButton: {
                    relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
                    position: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 60
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    })();
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is the example of the 3rd level drill down: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6r3ds0pw/  . In this demo, the 3rd level is hard coded. To create a fully working example with 3rd drilldown level (state-county-city) access to a standalone map of the certain county is necessary. For now, there is no such map in our map collection. You can find more information in the similar Highcharts forum thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=48440